# Set header 410 to parameter can remove index from serp?

Tags: seo, http-status-code-410

i need to set a 410 for pages that contains parameter stats with "?apple".
I try this code :`<?php if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?apple') !== false) { header("HTTP/1.0 410 Gone"); exit; } ?>`
i have some page link like : webiste.com/?apple , website.com/?apple-fruit
IF i use this code, the homepage will remove from Google  ?

Remove only the page with parameters, not the root.

Answer (score 0):

### If this is only a temporary problem

You can remove the URLs directly in Google Search Console by following the steps here: https://search.google.com/search-console/removals?resource_id=sc-domain%3Awebsite.com (replace "website.com" with your actual website)

You need to have the website registered in GSC for this to work.

### If you don't have access to GSC

I advise you to use [canonical URLs](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/consolidate-duplicate-urls) instead, this is common practice to make sure Google does not index canonical URLs such as "**/?apple**" parameters.

The simple fix for this would be to include this simple line in the  of each page pointing to itself:

eg. https://website.com/ gets:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://website.com/" />
```

and https://website.com/another-page/ gets:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://website.com/another-page/" />
```

this will prevent Google from putting the parameter URLs in the index.

Comment: Thanks mikulabc, where can i put canonical ? i have 200k fake pages with parameter after a japanese hack.

Comment: It depends on the CMS, is it WordPress? As I said, you put it in the meta <head>